# Looping over hierarchies of objects with Python

Tags: python, scripting, objects

Today I'm able to select all parameters that I need. But select a object it's pretty simple, using name it's ok.

But I use a very complex hierarchy in blender. As you can see just below:

[image]

Thereby I start with a simpler example and try to created a script just to print each object with their name and save the hierarchy, but some difficulties appears to me.

First I start to use `type` and be sure to conserve the hierarchy.

I decide to use an Empty as a "structure node".

So if I come across a Mesh I just print its name and if it's "EMPTY" I print its name. After printing all the mesh's names I check to see if another Empty is in the same block. I then go to the next one and do the same things. I do this for the entire group, it's a recursive function I think.

This is my Outliner:

[image]

But I have two difficulties:

First, I try this script to print the object, but didn't work well. I'm a newbi sorry if there is mistake. Could you help me to understand why it doesn't work?

[image]

Secondly, I tried something simpler, just to print by `type`, starting from the first one to the second one, but it seems to print by alphabetical order. I don't know what happened.

[image]

I've tried so many things in a week and now I'm here for your help. Could you take the time to help?

I am at your disposal for further information.

EDIT 25/07/2019

Hello evvery one,

So i try myself to find a solution, and it's pretty hard for me .

I created two function to created a list with all original parents

```
def explo_hie(id_scene): 
    global memoire_1
    global generation_1
    memoire_1=[]
    generation_1=[]
    for o in bpy.data.scenes[id_scene].objects:
        memoire_1.append(o.name) 
    ##
    k = len(memoire_1)
    ##
    for i in range(0,k) :
        if bpy.data.objects[memoire_1[i]].parent == None :
            generation_1.append(memoire_1[i])
            print("Add")
        else :
            print("Do nothing because has parent")
    ##
    print("First genration or origal parents",generation_1)
    ##
    w = len(generation_1)
    ##   
    for a in range (0,w):
        memoire_1.remove(generation_1[a])       
    ##
    print(memoire_1)

explo_hie("Scene")
```

And it's work pretty weel i'm pround of me, but i think there is some upgrades to do.

But my probleme is over the looping, because as you can see i created a code to check types of objects :

```
################       
#Step One 
################

# We need to knwo the len of the generation_1
#This list contains the first object of our generation
k = len(generation_1) 

#I scan all object of this list
#For each index i check the type           
for i in range(0,k) :
    type = bpy.data.objects[generation_1[i]].type
    if type == 'MESH': 
        print("Func grab mesh",type)
    elif type == 'EMPTY':
        print("It's a structural node",type)
    else :
        print("User you don't respect rules",type))
```

But as you can see it's note a reccursive fonction so i tried to do this :

```
################       
#Step Two 
################

# We need to knwo the len of the generation_1
#This list contains the first object of our generation
k = len(generation_1) 

#I scan all object of this list
#For each index i check the type           
for i in range(0,k) :
    type = bpy.data.objects[generation_1[i]].type
    if type == 'MESH': 
        print("Func grab mesh")
    elif type == 'EMPTY':
        print("It's a structural node",type)
        #But if it's a structural noed i need to check if it has children 
        nbr_enfants = bpy.data.objects[generation_1[i]].children
        if len(nbr_enfants) == 0 :
            print("Pas d'enfants fonction get info")
        else :
            print(nbr_enfants)
            a=len(nbr_enfants)
            for o in range(0,a) :
                e = nbr_enfants[o]
                print()
                type = bpy.data.objects[e].type
                if type == 'MESH': 
                    print("Fonction grab mesh")
                elif type == 'EMPTY':
                    print("reccursive func")
                else :
                    print("User you don't respect rules",type)         
    else :
        print("User you don't respect rules",type))
```

But i'm not able to created a the reccursive function ... and to be honnest i don't really understand how to do it. 
I try some simple exemple for algebric operation and i achiv it but for blender i don't know how to do it. Could you help me ?

Comment: `scene.objects` is all objects in scene. Use this if you are interested in all objects in a scene.  `ob.children` is a list of all immediate child objects.

Comment: Hi. Please explain it "didn't work well" in greater detail. *What* didn't go well? *What* happened? Use the [edit] link below your question to add more details.

Comment: Edit 25/07: I add infos about my work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Printing the hierarchy**

Note sure if this totally answers your question, but it shows how to traverse a hierarchy recursively.
Code similar from

[How do I copy children of an object using copy() method, without messing up their positions?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104886/how-do-i-copy-children-of-an-object-using-copy-method-without-messing-up-thei)

and [Show and Hide child objects along with Parent](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104530/show-and-hide-child-objects-along-with-parent)

Test script to recursively run thru the hierarchy.  Change the levels keyword argument to go deeper than 10.

```
import bpy
scene = bpy.context.scene

def print_heir(ob, levels=10):
    def recurse(ob, parent, depth):
        if depth > levels: 
            return
        print("  " * depth, ob.name)

        for child in ob.children:
            recurse(child, ob,  depth + 1)
    recurse(ob, ob.parent, 0)

root_obs = (o for o in scene.objects if not o.parent)

for o in root_obs:
    print_heir(o)
```

[image]

```
 Lamp
 Camera
   Cube.003
     Cube
       Cube.001
       Cube.005
 Cube.002
 Cube.004
```

Comment: Thx a lot, you help me so much and give me more informations to learn and trying to improve my knowledges  :-)