# Python: how to duplicate collections by listed names?

Tags: python, collections

I have a list with collection names
`collection_names = ["Collection", "Collection 2"]`
and I want to duplicate this collections.
How to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: no, it works only for selected collection

Comment: See 2nd answer, replace `context.collection` by `for col_name in collections_names:` then `col = bpy.data.collections.get(col_name)` and you should be good

Comment: With this changes it only copy last in list

Comment: Did you indent the code that follows too ?

Comment: my bad! Thanks for helping!

Comment: I cant reply in that thread, but that code did not copy object hierarchy, if collection have objects in object, it duplicate them without parenting

Comment: I'll comment on that answer asking for a possible solution since you don't have enough reputation for that, it shouldn't be more than a few lines. This should help : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/104990/86891

Comment: @APEC have modified the answer in dupe to parent to dupe if original parent is duped.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Found one strange behavior, after duplicate collection parented objects are shifted a little. If select them and clear parent, they place in right positions.

Comment: Sorry for mislead, children objects are shifted